# IOS: On logout/login, Google drive asks for permission grant everytime

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, google-drive-api

I integrated google drive sdk with my ios app. But the problem is when ever i logged out and log in into google drive it was asking me grant the permission every time. How to set asking this permission only once?.

-LOGANATHAN

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a refresh token. When you redirect the user to a google login page, you should add the following parameter `access_type=offline`, then when you exchange the code for an access token, it will also return a refresh_token. You need to make sure that you store the refresh token because normally you will only receive it the first time the user signs into your application. The process is explained here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline